# Align Image with 1 line inline elements

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my image alignment. I want my image to align with inline elements in a specific way.

This is what I have now:

```
                ######################
                #                    #
                #                    #
                #       image        #
                #                    #
                #                    #
inline elements ######################
```

but I want:

```
inline elements ######################
                #                    #
                #                    #
                #       image        #
                #                    #
                #                    #
                ######################
```

Is there anyway to do with with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Just assign `vertical-align: top` to the image's CSS.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBKpmJ

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS for image -  position:absolute

```
    img{
  position:absolute;
   }
```

codepen-http://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0):

css `float:left` on the inline element. See fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/djLqudmt/2/